# Laravel 5.0 custom 404 does not use middleware

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, middleware

I'm using a middleware to parse the output of the templates. This is working fine for all pages.

However when I want to show a 404 (got a custom page for that) it doesn't treat it as a http request (that's what I think) since it doesn't go through the middleware.

My question is, how to have ALL requests go through the middleware.

Comment: It'd help people answer if you specified **how** you're showing a custom 404 page.

Comment: laravel 5 has a 'errors' folder, I added a 404.blade.php in there.

Comment: Which middleware is not not using? Are you talking about terminating middleware? The problem is 404, 500 etc are display as the result of an Exception been thrown - so the system is handling an error response - not doing a normal output.

Comment: And what are your 'parsing' on the output anyway? Its just a 404 - there shouldnt really be much logic in that page anyway....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error pages don't go through the routes.php.

In `Kernel.php` move your middleware from the `$routeMiddleware` array to `$middleware` array.

Middleware in this array will run on every request (tested in 5.1).

[image: Image showing middleware and a 404 page]

Comment: This method can't be used always as some middlewares require web route specific data that is not yet available at that point.

Comment: +1 `The error pages don't go through the routes.php` This line should be in bold letters in documentation. It took me many days to know whats happening until this answer. @Björn can you please guide me how or where you get this info from?

Answer (score 8):

For people like me who spending hours in 2020 because of this weird behaviour...

Now in Laravel there is a new instrument «[Fallback Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#fallback-routes)».

Add this to `/routes/web.php`:

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    return view("404"); // template should exists
});
```

After that all requests will go throught middlewares.

Answer (score 1):

At Laravel 5.4 and probably some older ones you can modify the file `app/exceptions/Handler.php` and the function `render` like this:

```
if( is_a( $exception, \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException::class ) ) {
    return redirect()->route( 'error_404' );
}

// ... old code in the function ...
```

in this way every 404 errors are redirected to certain real route that acts like other routes of site.

You may also submit any data from current request to show a reasonable error at the target.

Answer (score 1):

I had a use case where api routes needs to always return json response.

All routes return json response <sub><sup>(laravel checks through $request->expectsJson())</sup></sub> IF user specifically ask for it by sending `accept: application/json` header.

But many a times user doesn't send the header and they get an html response instead.

As for my use case, all api routes will always send json response `we can force the routes to return json`, by manually attaching `accept: application/json` header using a middleware.

App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonOnAPIs.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Str;

class ForceJsonOnAPIs
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Force Json accept type on api routes
        if ($request->is('api/*') && !Str::contains($request->header('accept'), ['/json', '+json'])) {
            $request->headers->set('accept', 'application/json,' . $request->header('accept'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Register the middleware in `App\Http\Kernel.php`

```
// add the new middleware ForceJsonOnAPIs
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonOnAPIs::class,

    // rest of the middleware,
];
```

**Important:** You can assign the middle to `$middlewareGroups` in Kernel like web or api, But you will get into trouble when 404 exception occurs. The issue is `The error pages don't go through the routes.php` (Thanks to @Björn Answer above) thus the routes middleware won't get called and the 404 will return html response.

It's the same case for validation or authentication exceptions.

In my opinion, it's best to assign the middleware in the `$middleware` array as it runs on each request. This way all exceptions will automatically return correct exceptions as json in all routes.